# In Android, Can you write more than one object in a json file?

Tags: java, android, json

Until now, in Android, I was using json to write an object in it:
    file.writeString(Base64Coder.encodeString(json.prettyPrint(myclass)), false);

But, can I write more than one object in the same json file?

Thank's.

Comment: It sounds like you want an array.

Comment: Sure. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: you can create a whole data model class and use Gson to easily convert that class and all it subsets to Json with one swoop

Comment: Thank's i'll see that.

Answer (score 0):

Json is a string format. One serialized object here would be one string, but you can put new-line-delimited strings into the same file, effectively adding more objects to the same file.

Alternatively, you can add the objects to a list, then serialize the list, which will convert the list to a single Json string.